# Search within a string that does not contain a pattern

Tags: r, grepl

It appears that while `grep` has an invert argument, **`grepl`** does not.

I would like to subset for using 2 filters

```
data$ID[grepl("xyx", data$ID) & data$age>60]
```

How can I subset for age>60 and ID **not containing** "xyx"? What I did is

```
data$ID[abs(grepl("xyx", data.frame$ID)-1) & data$age>60]
```

which apparently works, but looks awful and unintuitive. Is there a nicer solution/argument?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`grepl` returns a logical vector.  You can use the `!` operator if you want the opposite result.

```
data$ID[!grepl("xyx", data$ID) & data$age>60]
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Aren't you glad you just have to type `!` instead of `invert=TRUE`? ;-)

Comment: compared to the (abs()-1), the sole '!' looks so much nicer....Maybe one of you experts with the 20k+ reputations may find some time and write a nice review post about string operations in R. Just like joran did about the *apply family here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega

Comment: Here's a try: http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/SvetlanaEdenRFiles/regExprTalk.pdf